# Show that $ \int_{0}^1 (1-u)^n\log(u) du = \frac{1}{(n+1)}\int_{0}^1\frac{(1-u)^{n+1}-1}{u}du $ are equal

Tags: calculus, integration

I have here 2 Integrals where I should show equality.

$ \int_{0}^1 (1-u)^nlog(u) du = \frac{1}{(n+1)}\int_{0}^1\frac{(1-u)^{n+1}-1}{u}du $

I tried with Integrate by parts. But i always got a part wich goes to infinity.

I'm looking forward to any hints.

/edit

I get 
$ \frac{1}{(n+1)}[(1-u)^{n+1}log(u)|_{0}^1+\int_{0}^1 \frac{(1-u)^{n+1}}{u} du  ]$

and my problem is, that $(1-u)^{n+1}log(u)|_{0}$ goes to infinity

Comment: What did you differentiate (your $u$) and what did you integrate (your $dv$) when you integrated by parts?

Comment: I integrated $(1-u)^n$ and differentiated $log(u)$

Comment: That seems right. Could you edit your question to show how far you got and where you ran into trouble?

Comment: Since your integral is improper, you should start out by taking the lower bound to be $c$ and then take the limit as $c \to 0^{+}$. Keep $c$ while you do your integration by parts. Also, when you integrate $(1-u)^n$, remember that *you* get to choose the constant of integration in the antiderivative, as long as what you're writing is an antiderivative of $(1-u)^n$. So you can try to pick the constant so that you don't have the problem you mentioned of a term tending to infinity.

Comment: There is a sign error: the antiderivative would be $-(1-u)^{n+1}/(n+1)$. (Don't forget the chain rule.) But here is where you can make a strategic choice. Pick $\frac{1}{n+1}[1-(1-u)^{n+1}]$ instead of $\frac{1}{n+1}[-(1-u)^{n+1}]$. As I said, *You* get to pick the constant of integration that you want. To take a simpler example, if $dv = 3x^2 \, dx$, you're free to choose $v = x^3$, but also $v = x^3 + 5$ if you like. Also, you should do the integration by parts with a lower bound $c > 0$, since the integral is improper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$f(u)=\frac{1}{n+1}\left((1-u)^{n+1}-1\right)$$
so
$$f'(u)=-(1-u)^n$$
and let
$$g'(u)=\frac 1 u$$
so $$g(u)=\log u$$
hence
$$\int_0^1f(u)g'(u)du=\frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^1\frac{(1-u)^{n+1}-1}{u}du=\underbrace{f(u)g(u)\bigg|_0^1}_{=I}-\int_0^1f'(u)g(u)du\\=\int_0^1(1-u)^n\log u du$$
and notice that $I=0$ since $f(1)g(1)=0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{u\to0}f(u)g(u)=0$